# Node + test: how to mock api using nock

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nock

Am trying to mock the api inside the unit test like the following:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const nock = require('nock');
const app = require('../app');

const agent = request.agent(app);
nock.disableNetConnect();
const userResponse = {
    user: {
      _id: '58828157ce4e140820e23648',
      info: {
        email: 'fake@test.io',
        password: '1',
        name: 'testx',
      },
};
  it('should register new user', (done) => {
    nock('http://localhost:5000')
      .post('/auth/register')
      .reply(200, userResponse);



    agent.post('/auth/register')
      .send({
        name: 'test',
        email: 'fake@test.io',
        password: '1',
      })
      .expect(200)
      .end((error, response) => {
        expect(response.body.user.info.email).to.equal('fake@test.io');
        expect(response.body.user.info.name).to.equal('test');
        done();
      });
  }).timeout(5000);
```

But am getting this error:

> NetConnectNotAllowedError: Nock: Not allow net connect for
>   "127.0.0.1:54877/auth/register"

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to allow nock to use localhost:
Add this line to your tes or global test config file.
`nock.enableNetConnect(/(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)/);`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [nock documentation](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#enabledisable-real-http-request). `nock.disableNetConnect` prevents real http request from happening, and it seems the endpoint you're trying to nock is running on a server on port 54877, but you seem to be attempting to nock a server running on port 5000.

Comment: Does this trick work? I mean i am facing the same issue in my test case need to upload few files but giving me " NetConnectNotAllowedError: Nock: Not allow net connect "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow requests to go to the internet for a certain domain, you can do:

```
const unBlockedDomains = ['toto.com', 'tata.fr'];
nock.enableNetConnect(host =>
  Boolean(unBlockedDomains.find(domain => host.includes(domain))),
);
```